# CAS client contacts CAS server for every request

Tags: java, spring, cas

I have configured CAS with Spring for SSO. Then I noticed that for every request, CAS client is contacting CAS server even after first login. Is this normal?

These are the server actions:

1. During authentication:

> ```
> ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
> ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
> ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
> ```

2. During subsequent calls:

> ```
> ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
> ```

So here for every request, client is contacting server and each time there is a new service ticket created.

But normally, client will contact server for the first time during authentication. For subsequent requests, it won't contact server.

Can any one of you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your client is not keeping track of the authenticated principal, usually in the application session.